# Change Router PPPoE Via SSH

Tags: ssh, modem

I would like to change my PPPoE settings for my modem via SSH, I have updated my DNS using ssh like so,

```
cd LANDevice_1_HostConfig

set DHCPServerConfigurable 1

set DNSServers 8.8.8.8
fcommit
```

I cannot seem to find the correct menu to update this the **PPPoE** information. The Modem is a Pace V2500.